# jquery - display image using hover

Tags: jquery, cakephp, hover, jquery-hover

I am currently working with CakePHP and jquery. I have get an array of desired results. I have to display that array as the output. One of the array value contains an "image ID" which is corresponds to the an image for the value in array. What I have to do is display those images only when I hover over the mouse on the data of array. Right now all the images are loaded when the page loads. That increases the loading time of page. With the hover approach, image will be called only when the mouse hovers and not when the page loads.

I am a newbie in jquery. I just wanted to know how it can be done. If someone shows me a some way to start, I can pull this off. Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need more information.

Regards,
BG

Comment: Adding an hover to the page wont decrease the loading time. You would need to use an AJAX call to the server when you mouseover something in your page.

Comment: What you are talking about is lazy loading ... there are many plugins out there for jQuery that do load images - but mainly when a page is scrolled - you could adapt them to use hover technique instead

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

HTML :

```
<div id="showImg">Show Images</div>
```

Javascript and jQuery :

```
$('#showImg').mouseover(function(){
    $.post('pathToCakeServerPage', function(data) {
        $('#showImg').append(data);
    });
});
```

here the documentation for Post - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
for mouseover - http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily using jquery .hover().

```
$(function() {
    $("THE CSS SELECTOR YOU WANT TO HOVER").hover(
    function () {
      $("THE CSS SELECTOR YOU WANT THE IMAGE IN").html('<img src="blabla.jpg" alt="" />');
    })

});
```

If you want blabla to be an ID, give your THE CSS SELECTOR YOU WANT TO HOVER an id and get that id using jquery